# Дискорд Бот не отвечает на команды в дискорде

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Я перепробывал все гайды как делать дискорд бота, бот запускается но вот ответить на команды он не может, ни в какую.
В консоли ошибки не выводило

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import config



client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=discord.Intents.default())


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {client.user.name}')

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx: commands.Context):
    await ctx.send('Pong!')

    
client.run(config.BotToken)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос уже часто поднимается, дублирую ответ вновь:

Добавьте после импорта вот эти строчки:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '/', intents=intents)
```

Затем зайдите на discord.com/developers и выберите Вашего бота. Затем зайдите в раздел **Bot** и поставьте галочку на **"MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT Required for your bot to receive message content in most messages"**

Бот будет работать на серверах. В данный момент, бот у Вас работает только в личных сообщениях.

Comment: Спасибо, просто не нашел решения в инете и пришлось спросить тут

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста, я за любые вопросы, независимо от сложности.
Если данный ответ смог решить Вашу проблемы, буду рад, если выберете его решением.

Удачных разработок!